# In Nginx, block user based on X header value

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have 6 Nginx servers behind load balancer.  Of course, if I just try to "deny" based on IP address it does not work as the app servers just see the load balancer IP.

However, I learned about the Real IP module and I have that enabled in the following way:

```
set_real_ip_from   0.0.0.0/0;
real_ip_header     X-Real-IP;
```

So, now that I have the X-Real_IP header set correctly, how I can then configure Nginx to use block certain users who's "X-Real-IP" value equals a set of IPs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy. Nginx's "geo" module lets define a variable with value depending on the client's IP address:

```
geo $ban_ip {
  default 0;
  10.1.0.0/24 1;
};
```

`geo` directive should be at `http` level (e.g. outside `server`). There is a convenient way to include large IP databases via `include` or `ranges`, see the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html)

So, assuming you have such a variable, you may return whatever status codes you'd like, e.g.  403 or 404 (at `server` level or in `location`):

```
if ($ban_ip) {
  return 403;
}
```

If you'd like to silently drop the connection, use

```
if ($ban_ip) {
  return 444;
}
```

`444` is a non-standard status code used internally to instruct Nginx to drop the connection. (thus a client does not see it)

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Application Firewall 3rd Party module for nginx called naxsi](http://code.google.com/p/naxsi/), I think it could handle the problem.