# What is simple way to ensure that HTTP request with some specific header come only from a specific IP only?

Tags: centos6, http-headers, intrusion-prevention

My web application run on Centos6.
I want to protect my application.
I want to ensure that HTTP request with some specific header come only from a specific IP only.

(The header include a user name and I want to prevent HTTP header spoofing).

**Important clarification:** Requests without the specific header should be allowed from any IPs

Is it possible to do it with IPTable?
Other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this at web server level, which is application level and where your HTTP Headers are visible. iptables can't handle HTTP headers, because it handles layer 3 and HTTP is layer 7.

Check the OSI model.
You can use nginx or apache2 for this

Here are two similar questions and their answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970620/nginx-reject-request-if-header-is-not-present-or-wrong

[In Nginx, block user based on X header value](https://serverfault.com/questions/361310/in-nginx-block-user-based-on-x-header-value)